# Selenium webdriver wait doesn't seem to work in case of overlay

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There is an overlay ( a grey color translucent screen ) that comes up when ever one clicks Login button and it stays for few seconds. Because of this, selenium web driver isn't able to find the elements as this overlay kinds of hides them for a while or at least that is what looks to me. How can I handle this? I don't find `Thread.sleep` to be an efficient way here.

I tried -

```
    public void login(){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);     

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("ajax-overlay"))));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.id("okbutton))));
        driver.findElement(By.id("username)).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("okbutton")).click();   
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("ajax-overlay"))));
}
```

but nothing seems to work and I still get error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button id="loginDialog:okButton" name="loginDialog:okButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-panel-titlebar-icon synchronous" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'loginDialog:okButton',process:'loginDialog:okButton loginDialog:username loginDialog:password loginDialog:okButton',update:'startingCashFocus loginDialog:dialogFocus loginDialog:lblPassword loginDialog:lblUsername loginDialog:messages',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){handleLoginAttempt(xhr, status, args, loginWidget, null); ;}});return false;" tabindex="1" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">...</button> is not clickable at point (931, 250). Other element would receive the click: <div id="ajax-overlay" class="ui-blockui ui-widget-overlay ui-helper-hidden eternal" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Also, there is no way to find out the overlay id and thankfully, selenium gave it in its error details.

Comment: Please share your trial code which clicks element, After this line : wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.id("okbutton"))));

Comment: Updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Please update your question title, It is not about webdriver wait. Your exception details says something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to click element with one of the following method, which will solve this Exception :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id('okbutton'))).click().perform();
```

OR

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id('okbutton')));
```

Comment: Thank you, Ishita. The second one works. The first one doesn't and the reason is obvious I think as if it would work, then normal click would also work because click is getting done but on the overlay. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @apun Please upvote, If you think it has helped you to solve problem.

Comment: Surely. I already chosen it as an answer. Up voted. Thank you, it surely helped.